# How can I make VS Code not wait after running a debug app in an external terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I find many questions about the opposite, which seem to be fixed by the behaviour I want to get rid of.

When I debug my app I always get

```
Press any key to continue . . .
```

in the (now empty) external window.

The app is a text gui app (think vim), there is never anything useful in the window. I want the external window to close when I stop the app or stop debugging. But I cannot find a switch to do this

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is mostly by design, and is currently not configurable.

[Quoting @weinand](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63813#issuecomment-726696727):

> initially we were closing the terminal immediately at the end of a debug session but with that behavior user complained that they couldn't see runtime errors or program output. That's the reason why the "Press any key to continue..." && wait was added. IIRC the idea was to keep the terminal open if there are issues (exit code != 0) and to close it otherwise.

(see the rest of the linked quote for more useful info from @weinand)

VS Code itself is limited in what it can do in terms of providing configuration settings to control this. Again, [quoting @weinand](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63813#issuecomment-750843776):

> support for external terminals is provided by individual debug extensions. VS Code doesn't know about them and cannot provide a generic property in the launch.json.
>
> But an individual debug extension could provide such an option. Please file a feature request against the extension.

Some workarounds people have found:

- configure the external terminal setting to point to a wrapper program that takes VS Code's commandline with the additional statement that causes the prompt to happen, and then removes that prompt from the command string before executing the rest. ([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63813#issuecomment-442294612))
- write a `postDebugTask` that executes a system command to kill the terminal processes ([source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63813#issuecomment-818912175))

You can see the rest of the discussion in that issue ticket for other discussion on ways to address the problem, and subscribe to it to get updates on its status.

Loosely related issue ticket, but about *integrate* (not external) terminals: [runInTerminalRequest shows unnecessary output when kind: integrated
#100538](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/100538).

Comment: I also note that he said 'That's the reason why the "Press any key to continue..." && wait was added.' It was added, it should be easy to make it optional. Sigh